# I don't get thread synchronization much at all

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So I've read quite about Thread Synchronization in Java. I'm currently trying the Bounded-Buffer problem. The producer will keep producing a product on the buffer while the consumer keeps consuming it.

The producer will wait if the buffer is full before producing another product.
The consumer will wait if the buffer is empty.

However, my problem is that the producer only starts producing when the buffer is empty until the it is full. The consumer only starts consuming when the buffer is full until it is empty.

Example (buffer size: 5)

```
Produced Product 1
Produced Product 2
Produced Product 3
Produced Product 4
Produced Product 5
Consumed Product 1
Consumed Product 2
Consumed Product 3
Consumed Product 4
Consumed Product 5
Produced Product 6
Produced Product 7
Produced Product 8
Produced Product 9
Produced Product 10
Consumed Product 6
Consumed Product 7
Consumed Product 8
Consumed Product 9
Consumed Product 10
Produced Product 11
Produced Product 12
Produced Product 13
Produced Product 14
Produced Product 15
Consumed Product 11
Consumed Product 12
Consumed Product 13
Consumed Product 14
Consumed Product 15
Produced Product 16
Produced Product 17
Produced Product 18
Produced Product 19
Produced Product 20
Consumed Product 16
Consumed Product 17
Consumed Product 18
Consumed Product 19
Consumed Product 20
Produced Product 21
Produced Product 22
Produced Product 23
Produced Product 24
Produced Product 25
Consumed Product 21
Consumed Product 22
Consumed Product 23
Consumed Product 24
Consumed Product 25
Produced Product 26
Produced Product 27
Produced Product 28
Produced Product 29
Produced Product 30
Consumed Product 26
Consumed Product 27
Consumed Product 28
Consumed Product 29
Consumed Product 30
```

I want it so that the producer produces as long as the buffer is not full, whether or not the buffer is empty. Subsequently, I want it so that the consumer consumes as long as the buffer is not empty, whether or not the buffer is full.

What's wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProducerConsumer{

    final static Queue<Product> buffer = new LinkedList<>();
    private static int buffer_size, no_items, itemno = 1;
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            buffer_size = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Buffer size (default: 5)"));
            if(buffer_size<0){
                buffer_size = 5;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            buffer_size = 5;
        }
        try{
            no_items = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input No. of Items (default: 10)"));
            if(no_items<0){
                no_items = 10;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            no_items = 10;
        }
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

    static class Product {
        private String name = "Product X";
        private int productno;

        public Product(int productno) {
            this.productno = productno;
            this.name = "Product "+productno;
        }
        public int number() {
            return productno;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    static class Producer extends Thread{
        public Producer(){
        }
        public void produce(){
            Product p = new Product(itemno++);
            try {
                this.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
            buffer.add(p);
            System.out.println("Produced "+p);
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(buffer){
                while(itemno<=no_items){
                    while(buffer.size()==buffer_size){
                        try{
                            buffer.wait(100);
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                            Thread.interrupted();
                        }
                    }
                    produce();
                    buffer.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static class Consumer extends Thread{
        public Consumer(){
        }
        public boolean consume(){
            try {
                this.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
            Product product = buffer.remove();
            System.out.println("Consumed "+product);
            return product.number()==no_items;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(buffer){
                boolean end = false;
                while(!end){
                    while(buffer.isEmpty()){
                        try{
                            buffer.wait(100);
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                            Thread.interrupted();
                        }
                    }
                    end = consume();
                    buffer.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, on a side note.  You should be using `Thread.sleep(millis)` not `this.sleep(millis)`.  `sleep` is a static method that is always executed on `Thread.currentThread()` which in turn works out for you because you are using it in that fashion, but it may burn you in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have acquired the `buffer` monitor and produced N times before notifyAll and releasing the buffer monitor via exiting the `synchronized` block, all inside the while loop.

Try putting `while` outside of the `synchronized` blocks, so you give the other thread a chance to acquire the lock during concurrent produces/consumes.

Note that `notifyAll` does not actually effect other threads until the notifying thread has exited the `synchronized` region

Edit:  I ran it after making the suggested changes and I got the following output

```
Produced Product 1
Produced Product 2
Produced Product 3
Consumed Product 1
Consumed Product 2
Consumed Product 3
Produced Product 4
Produced Product 5
Consumed Product 4
Consumed Product 5
Produced Product 6
Consumed Product 6
Produced Product 7
Produced Product 8
Produced Product 9
Produced Product 10
Consumed Product 7
Consumed Product 8
Consumed Product 9
Consumed Product 10
```

Comment: In fact, try to restrict synchronisation to the smallest possible block of code. (So, for example, you shouldn't really call `sleep()` in it.)

Comment: Minor nitpick: The monitor is also released by calling `wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both threads are synchronized on buffer, only one of the threads will be running at any time. One thread signals the other to resume running and suspends itself when it calls buffer.wait(). The logic in the while loops that contain the buffer.wait() calls, (buffer.size() == buffer_size) and (buffer.isEmpty()), allow the loop to only run when it's function (either producer or consumer) has been completed and cannot continue.

The program is executing like this: Producer will produce 5 items, then the while loop condition will be true and it will call buffer.wait() to allow consumer to run. Consumer will start running and consume until buffer is empty, in which case the while condition will be true and it will call buffer.wait() and allow producer to run again.

To allow both threads to run simultaneously, which is probably what you're really after, you should call synchronize(buffer) only when you need safe access to the buffer. One way to do it is the following code block:

```
static class Producer extends Thread {
    public Producer() {
    }

    public void produce() {
        Product p = new Product(itemno++);
        try {
            this.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
        synchronized(buffer) {
            buffer.add(p);
        }
        System.out.println("Produced " + p);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (itemno <= no_items) {
            while (buffer.size() == buffer_size) {
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }

            produce();
        }
    }
}

static class Consumer extends Thread {
    public Consumer() {
    }

    public boolean consume() {
        try {
            this.sleep(r.nextInt(100));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }

        Product product;
        synchronized (buffer) {
            product = buffer.remove();
        }

        System.out.println("Consumed " + product);
        return product.number() == no_items;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean end = false;
        while (!end) {
            while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TrashMe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            end = consume();
        }
    }
}
```